# PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, android, mysql

**UPDATE 
thank you that solved the problem , but now I get this error "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. " I turned off the firewall and I don't have any antiviruse software**

I'm following this tutorial to connect android app to the database
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

I'm hosting my php file in WAMPSERVER PHP Version 5.4.3 I get these two errors 
I've been trying to fix this error for hours but no luck could you please help me fix it

**" Warning: require_once(C:\wamp\wwwC:\wamp\www\db_connect.php): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\get_property_details.php on line 12"**

and this error

**"Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\wwwC:\wamp\www\db_connect.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\get_property_details.php on line 12"**

these are my files 
db_config.php

```
define('DB_USER', "student"); 
define('DB_PASSWORD', "student2"); 
define('DB_DATABASE', "test"); 
define('DB_SERVER', "student.database.university.ac.uk"); 
?>
```

db_connect.php

```
<?php


class DB_CONNECT {

    function __construct() {

        $this->connect();
    }


    function __destruct() {

        $this->close();
    }


    function connect() {

       require_once __DIR__ . "C:\\wamp\\www\\db_config.php";

        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

        return $con;
    }


    function close() {

        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>
```

get_student_details.php

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will get single student details
 * A student is identified by student id (student_id)
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . "C:\\wamp\\www\\db_connect.php";

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["student_id"])) {
    $student_id = $_GET['student_id'];

    // get a student from students table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_STUDENT WHERE student_id = $student_id");

    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $student = array();
            $student["student_id"] = $result["student_id"];
            $student["student_fname"] = $result["student_fname"];
            $student["student_lastName"] = $result["student_lastName"];
            $student["address"] = $result["address"];
            $student["postcode"] = $result["postcode"];
            $student["grade"] = $result["grade"];

            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["student"] = array();

            array_push($response["student"], $student);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no student found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No student found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no student found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No student found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Quick note, you should move away from **mysql** and use **mysqli** as mysql is deprecated and will be removed

Answer (score 4):

```
require_once __DIR__ . "C:\\wamp\\www\\db_config.php";
```

The above line is your problem. You're path is wrong because you are telling PHP the file is located in the current directory and in a path called "C:\wamp\www\db_config.php" which clearly is incorrect.

Your fix *probably* is to remove the `__DIR__` which is not necessary since you seem to have the full patgh to the file already:

```
require_once "C:\\wamp\\www\\db_config.php"
```

Comment: Would be better to use the relative path to the file rather than absolute though.

Comment: I would say is it is better to use a dynamic full path to the file.

Comment: thank you that solved the problem , but now I get this error "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. " I turned off the firewall and I don't have any antiviruse software